# Kerberos setup giving error with Storm UI

Tags: apache-storm, kerberos

I have setup the Kerberos authentication with Active Directory for Apache Storm.
Supervisor and Nimbus daemons are running fine after kerberos setup.
On adding the following lines in the storm.yaml file:

```
ui.filter: "org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter"
ui.filter.params : {‘type’: ‘kerberos’,
                    ‘kerberos.principal’: ‘HTTP/ui.host.abc.com@XYZ.COM’,
                    ‘kerberos.keytab’: ‘/etc/security/keytabs/HTTP.keytab’,
                    ‘kerberos.name.rules’: ‘DEFAULT’}
```

Getting the following error in logs:

```
Failed to login as [HTTP@DOMAIN.COM]
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No key to store
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException:
    javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No key to store
```

I have checked the HTTP.keytab. The permissions are correct and it is not empty with a valid principal.

I can even do ssh login with HTTP user in the machine.

There is not a proper documentation for Kerberos intration with Storm that talks about this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe http://serverfault.com is a better place to ask such kind of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out it was due to a typo.
Had to put HTTP/DOMAIN.COM in place of HTTP@DOMAIN.COM in the pricipal placeholder.